# Magento API - Update Product and "Use Default Value" checkboxes

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm using the Magento API to update Products for a store running Magento 2.2.5. I'm performing a simple update request containing a payload like this:

```
    {
  "product": {
    "extensionAttributes": {
      "stockItem": {
        "isInStock": false, 
        "qty": 0
      }
    }, 
    "sku": "9854112"
  }, 
  "saveOptions": true
}
```

to the Products endpoint Products endpoint e.g. `/rest/V1/products/9854112`.

The store owner has advised that after an update for the different store views the checkboxes to `Use Default Value` of a given field would be disabled. They referred me to this fix:

https://www.cadence-labs.com/2018/03/magento-2-use-default-value-store-view-scope-fix/

but after performing a Product update via the API the checkboxes are reverted again.

I can't see anything in the Product docs that would allow me to specify that the `Use Default Value` checkbox should remain checked - is this possible to achieve via the API when updating a Product? Or is there another way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass this problem using n98-magerun. You can script it or using an observer and run   eav:attributes:restore-use-default-value